# Persistent connection in laravel queue worker

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to setup a service on my laravel application with third party library for connecting to provider.

Its code goes as follows

```
$connection = new CustomConnection();
$connection->refresh();
$connection->sendMessage('user@myapp.com', ['message'=>'something', 'ttl'=>3600]);
$connection->refresh();
$connection->sendMessage('user2@myapp.com', ['message'=>'something', 'ttl'=>3600]);
$connection->close();
```

My goal is to keep the connection connected while sending message via laravel queue worker.

Something like if que worker establishes

```
$connection = new CustomConnection();
$connection->refresh();
```

Executes `$connection->refresh()` every 5 seconds & whenever job is added in queue it should execute

```
$connection->sendMessage('user@myapp.com', ['message'=>'something', 'ttl'=>3600]);
$connection->refresh();
```

Block of code.

I have no clue how laravel's core queue works in backend and if I can override it's functionality and how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In your service provider, register the connection (or a service that uses the connection) as a *singleton*. Declare this as a dependency for your job, and all your jobs will have the same connection/service instance for the lifetime of the queue worker.

There's no way you can execute $connection->refresh() every fifth second. If the purpose of this call is some kind of heartbeat/healthcheck, listen for the [queue-related events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#job-events) and use these instead. A combination of JobProcessing, JobProcessed, JobFailed and Looping will allow you to execute code before and after jobs execute. You can use these to evaluate if you should call $connection->refresh(), like if at least five seconds has passed since last invocation.

There's no event you can use to run code when a job is dispatched.

Do not attempt to override the internal workings of the queue system. There's no promises of backward compatibility between different Laravel releases, and you'll have to keep track of all (possible) subtle changes that are introduced upstream.

Answer (score 0):

**Allows persisting database sessions between queue jobs***
This pull request allows persisting database sessions between queue jobs. To opt-in to this behavior, users simply need set the VAPOR_QUEUE_DATABASE_SESSION_PERSIST environment variable to true. Allowing to make a very simple job that uses the database at least once, up to 45% faster in a 512MB lambda functions.
https://github.com/laravel/vapor-core/pull/97